# How do I check whether the right/left edge of an element is overlapping the side of it's container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a right / left navigation arrow within a container (the arrows replace the existence of a scrollbar) when the corresponding edge of the content overlaps the container's sides.

Also, when the content is scrolled all the way to the end and can't scroll any further, the arrow should disappear.

[image]

My problem is, I'm confused as to how I write the function to check whether the element's contents are overlapping one edge or the other to hide one arrow or the other.

I started writing logic like this:

```
function setArrows(elem){
    if (elem.scrollLeft() > 0) { //scroll position is greater than zero
        // show left arrow
    } 
    if () { //scroll position is less than zero
        //show right arrow
    }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to be the right logic. It sounded simpler in my head before I went to actually write the function.

**How do I check whether the right/left edge of an element is overlapping the side of it's container?**

Here's a Stack Snippet:

```js
$('#wrapper').scroll(function(){
  //check edges
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
#content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about adding some html and creating a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You have better chance of achieving what you want with [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/). Hint : If it overflow left, the `left` property will be negative. If it overflow right, the `left + width` will be higher than the parent width.

Comment: Insert one div inside another. Parent one should have overflow:hidden. Then compare parent's div width with child's width. Then you can check if you have to show the arrow. It's a good start.

Comment: @caramba Aren't Stack Snippets the new hotness these days? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the content width minus the scrollLeft is greater than the wrapper width. If it is show the right scroller..

Something like this

```js
$(function() {
  var content = $('#content'),
    arrows = $('.arrow'),
    wrapper = $('#wrapper').scroll(function() {
      //check edges

      // handle left arrow
      if (this.scrollLeft > 0) {
        arrows.filter('.left').addClass('visible');
      } else {
        arrows.filter('.left').removeClass('visible');
      };

      // handle right arrow
      if (content.outerWidth() - this.scrollLeft > wrapper.width()) {
        arrows.filter('.right').addClass('visible');
      } else {
        arrows.filter('.right').removeClass('visible');
      };

    });

  arrows.on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is('.left')) {
      wrapper[0].scrollLeft -= 100;
    } else {
      wrapper[0].scrollLeft += 100;
    }
    return false;
  });

  // initialize
  wrapper.trigger('scroll');
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/100/abstract/2') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#full-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.arrow.visible {
  display: block;
}
.arrow.left {
  left: 0
}
.arrow.right {
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="full-container">
  <div class="arrow left">&lt;</div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow right">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even in a simple snippet demonstration I would suggest fixing those global variable declarations; Never know when your code will be a source of learning for a new JS learner.